# I cannot deploy the back-end of my app in render.com

Tags: node.js, deployment, backend, openai-api, render.com

I am currently trying to deploy my react web application and started by deploying my backend. However, I have an issue with deployment. here is my package.json in the backend of my program. It is possible that I should deploy the frontend first and then I should deploy the backend. In my web I have used node.js and I have used mongodb. I have used JavaScript in my frontend.

I put npm install as a building command, and "npm start" as a running command in render.com.

my question is could someone explain what this error is and how to solve it, please?

here is a link to the github repository. https://github.com/makimakiver/tuba

errors from render.com:

```
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM    throw err;
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM    ^
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  Error: Cannot find module 'node:fs'
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  Require stack:
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/_shims/node-runtime.js
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/_shims/auto/runtime-node.js
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/_shims/index.js
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/core.js
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/index.js
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/routes/posts.js
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  - /opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/server.js
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/_shims/node-runtime.js:37:19)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19) {
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM    requireStack: [
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/_shims/node-runtime.js',
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/_shims/auto/runtime-node.js',
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/_shims/index.js',
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/core.js',
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/node_modules/openai/index.js',
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/routes/posts.js',
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM      '/opt/render/project/src/Tuba-Backend/server.js'
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM    ]
Sep 28 03:47:04 PM  }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "npm i"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "all": "^0.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.2.4",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "openai": "^4.10.0"
  }
}
```

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts")
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth")
const userRoute = require("./routes/users")
const teamRoute = require("./routes/team")
const AIRoute = require("./routes/AI")
const uploadRoute = require("./routes/upload")
const otpRoute = require("./routes/otp")
const path = require("path")
const PORT = 5000;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// import dotenv file to protect my password from third party
require("dotenv").config();
// connecting to database
// protecting password from being revealed to third party
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOURL)
    .then(()=>{console.log("connected");})
    .catch((err)=>{console.log(err);})
// identify whether it is connected if it is connected it will return "connected"
// if not then it will return error

// midle-ware set up
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public/images")))
app.use(express.json())
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);
app.use("/api/team", teamRoute);
app.use("/api/AI", AIRoute);
app.use("/api/upload", uploadRoute);
app.use("/api/otp", otpRoute);

// app.get("/", (req,res) => {
//     res.send(" can u hear me? ")
// })
app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log("server is activated"));
```

Comment: Which version of node are you running locally, and what version have you specified in render? Take a look at https://render.com/docs/node-version 
It's likely the version you're running in render is different than the one you expect to have.

Comment: Hi I ran a code "node -v" and I have got v19.4.0 .is it different ?

Comment: Did you specify the `NODE_VERSION` in render to be 19.4.0 like that render docs page suggests?

Comment: I solved the issue thank you very much!

Comment: Cool! Maybe add what you did as an answer and mark it as accepted?